# Android - Stop a Service from a different class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

In the application i'm making I want to start an intent in one activity

```
Intent toonService = new Intent(Login.this, ToonService.class);
toonService.putExtra("toonName", result.getName());
Login.this.startService(toonService);
```

Will the following code close the intent i just opened? If not how can i get it to?

```
Intent toonService = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ToonService.class);
MainActivity.this.stopService(toonService);
```

the second piece of code would be called at a time completly unrelated to the first piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, assuming you only want one instance of this service running at once you could hold a static variable in the service class and access it from anywhere. Example;

```
public class ToonService extends Service{

    public static ToonService toonService;

    public ToonService(){
        toonService = this;
    }
    ...

}
```

The constructor for ToonService now stores the created instance in the static variable `toonService`. Now you can access that service from anywhere from the class. Example below;

```
ToonService.toonService.stopSelf();
```

You could also handle multiple instances by having the class store a static `List` of running instances, rather than just the single instance. [It is worth noting](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping), that when you tell a service to stop, you are only **requesting** that it is stopped. Ultimately the Android OS will determine when it is closed.

Comment: I don't think `public static toonService` is valid. (It's missing the type)

Comment: @JoshM - Quite right, well spotted. I will correct it.

Comment: doesnt work...you can't stop ToonService.toonService you have to stop an intent.

Comment: @user3293629 - Answer amended, give that a go. `ToonService.toonService.stopSelf();`

Comment: looks like it should work, but i actually ended up just checking an external database to figure out when the stopSelf() should be called

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can close the service from another activity.

Method-1: Do the following steps
1. Write a method in Activity 1 that returns that activity reference.
2. Write a method in Activity 1 that closes the service.
3. In Activity2 call the first method and get the reference. Using that reference call the second method

```
1. private static Context context=this;
   public static  Context getContext(){
        return context;
   }

2. public void stop(){
       //stop the service here
   }

3.  In activity 2
     Activity context=Activity1.getContext();
     context.stop();
```

Method 2: follow the following steps.

1. Write a BroadcastReceiver as an inner class in Activity1 . In onReceive() stop the service.
2. Broadcast the intent from the second Activity.

Comment: when would i call the getContext() method?

Comment: since stop() is a non-static method we need that class reference for calling this method. so for getting that class reference we use gerContext() method.   for example: Activity1.getContext().stop().