# Stop a service that was run by another class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I've a `Fragment` **fr**, `Service` **ser**, `BroadcastReceiver` **brc**.

In **fr** I have a switch, when checked it launches **ser**, when un-checked it stops it, so far so good.

In **ser**, I have registered a `BroadcastReceiver` named **brc** and added an `IntentFilter` named **USER_PRESENT**, When the device is locked, I have the `Service` call `stopSelf()` and register that `BroadcastReceiver`, when the phone is unlocked, `onReceive()` will be called, in that method I've added a code to start the `Service` again .

Now, the problem .. I can't stop the `Service` when the switch is un-checked, even though I'm calling `stopService(intentname);` .

And my guess is, it's a different `Intent` which launched by a different class. So I've stopped that `Intent` like this:

`stopService(brc.intentname);`

Nothing happened and the `Service` keeps running. What's the solution for this?.

Code:

**Fragment**:

```
if ( !Switched ) {
    getActivity().startService(ServiceIntent);
} 
if( Switched ){
    getActivity().stopService(ServiceIntent);
    getActivity().stopService(BroadcastTest.ServiceIntent);

}
```

**Service**:

```
if( !isScreenOn && isLocked )
{
    this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastTest(), new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"));
    CancelTimer();
    stopSelf();
}
```

**BroadcastTest**:

```
ServiceIntent = new Intent(context, Service.class);
context.startService(ServiceIntent);
```

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I've added the codes

Comment: I've thought about adding a boolean to check if Service Switch is enabled or not, if not it will stopself, But i'd like to know why it's not stopping .

Comment: Yes____________(for length policy)

Comment: Personally, I always call "startService()" with an Intent with an action like "my.package.name.STOP" and then evaluate the action in "onStartCommand()" and let the service call "stopSelf()". Now I just found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9665584/5015207) to a similar problem which shows I'm not the only one to do so (very reassuring :) )

Comment: And I think you may be right with your guess about the different Intents.

Comment: Please check exactly the content of the `Intent` that you pass to `stopService()`. Add logging that logs the exact content of this `Intent`. I'm guessing that the `Intent` doesn't contain what you think it should contain.

Comment: DavidWasser Can you please explain a bit more ?, @0X0nosugar I'm gonna try you way and see, I'm sure it will work, But i'd like to know why the service isn't stopping, And another thing, How about i send a broadcast to "BroadcastTest" with action, and check if the action "stop", i can stop it from the BroadcastTest, rather than stopping it from the fragment which didn't work.

Comment: Just saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100189/android-stop-a-service-from-a-different-class?rq=1 , looks promising.

Comment: Update, I have switched the way to start the service, I've sent a broadcast to BroadcastTest with "start" action, and then the service starts, and when un-checked, it will send a "stop" action, all good so far, but the damn service is still running!
I'm starting and stopping the same service, as someone said abot services, i'm requesting to be stopped, not force to stop, maybe that's the reason ? Or it's registering / un-registering broadcast problem ?

Comment: How do you know your `Service` is still running?

Comment: Post the code from your `onStartCommand()`